# code only working after second click, simple php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple program in php that reads a text file with songs and then prints them on screen with a delete button next to each song and then when you click the delete button the song should delete. The new file is written to the txt file and and should be refreshed on screen. My code is only working after the second click. The first click actually does modify the txt file but the code on screen doesn't refresh.

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Music</title>
<body>
<h1>My Music</h1>
<p>My Library</p>

<?php
//read file
$myFile = "test.txt";
//file to array
$lines  = file($myFile);
//set array length
$length = count($lines);
//print array on screen with delete button
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    echo $lines[$i] . '<form action="index.php" method="post">
                     <button type="submit" name="test" value="' . $i . '">Delete</button><br><br></form>';
}


//after clicking delete box remove song from array 
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    //getting song number to remove
    $songNumber = $_POST['test'];
    //removing song from original array  
    array_splice($lines, $songNumber, 1);
    //open test.txt again
    $myFile2 = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    //set updated array length
    $length = count($lines);
    //write array to test.txt
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $txt = $lines[$i];
        fwrite($myFile2, $txt);
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

text file i'm using

```
1. turkish march
2. claire de lune
3. symphony no. 9
4. swan lake
5. imperial march
6. helter skelter
```

Comment: This is due to you echoing out the file data before modifying it, so you are effectively 1 request behind.  Move `if (isset($_POST['test'])) { ... }` above the output of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the order of things your code does.  First it reads from the file and displays the data.  *Then* it deletes a line from the file.  *After* the file has already been displayed.

Just swap the order of events:

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    // perform your delete
}

// Display the contents of the file
$myFile = "test.txt";
// etc.
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: before I finish writing my answer you posted yours, man you are fast!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file then removing the title, when you click the button you read the unmodified version then modified it that's why it works on the second refresh.. or click.. Change the order of your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Music</title>
<body>
<h1>My Music</h1>
<p>My Library</p>

<?php

//after clicking delete box remove song from array 
// remove file first if needed...
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    //getting song number to remove
    $songNumber = $_POST['test'];
    //removing song from original array  
    array_splice($lines, $songNumber, 1);
    //open test.txt again
    $myFile2 = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    //set updated array length
    $length = count($lines);
    //write array to test.txt
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $txt = $lines[$i];
        fwrite($myFile2, $txt);
    }
}

//read file
$myFile = "test.txt";
//file to array
$lines  = file($myFile);
//set array length
$length = count($lines);
//print array on screen with delete button
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    echo $lines[$i] . '<form action="index.php" method="post">
                     <button type="submit" name="test" value="' . $i . '">Delete</button><br><br></form>';
}



?>
</body>
</html>
```